# Python syslog and extended characters

Tags: python, python-2.7, utf-8, syslog

I am confused about how Python's syslog wrapper handles unicode text. In particular I am interested when Python is running in Ubuntu/Debian. For instance, if you open a python shell in your command line and type these commands, how come the first one gives an ascii error and the second one works?

Does syslog not know how to handle unicode text? Is there something I can configure to make the encode('utf8') part automatic for all syslogs? Thank you in advance for any help you can offer me.

```
from syslog import syslog

extended_chars = u"∞§¶¡™£¢"
syslog( "test: %s" % extended_chars )
syslog( ( "test: %s" % extended_chars ).encode( 'utf8' ) )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

python has two types of strings: byte-strings and unicode strings, and the `syslog()` function requires that its argument be a byte string.

The `.encode()` method transforms a unicode string into a byte string.

In your program we have the following string types:

```
extended_chars                                - unicode string
("test: %s" % extended_chars)                 - unicode string
("test: %s" % extended_chars).encode('utf8')  - byte string
```

Per your question in the comments...

I'm not sure it is documented anywhere. In general, any function which is just a wrapper around a system call or a libc function should be given byte strings. However, for convenience, system calls which take path names will automatically translate unicode strings to byte strings via `.encode('utf8')` since utf8 is the most common encoding used for file names.

Note that `file.write(...)` needs to be passed a byte string, e.g.:

```
with open("foo", "w") as f:
  f.write( extended_chars )                # fails
  f.write( extended_char.encode('utf8') )  # works
```

and that `file.read()` will read bytes, so to get unicode characters from a file you need to use:

```
  f.read().decode('utf8')
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer @user5402, do you know where this requirement is documented? Thanks again.